# How to reshape the input for Conv1D with 1 Dimensional data (Keras)?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

My data looks like this:

[image]

10000 columns = features and 68 rows = samples. Omit the first column which is the label.

How can I reshape it in the proper manner. Currently the performance is quite bad. And I'm guessing it's the encoding.

I'm struggling to see which dimension is which which since my data is 1 dimensional.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WAC880IyTce48r9gK3-93hakKXDz6mZl?usp=sharing) is the dataset.

Or a minimal representation:

```
30, 0.5, 0.2, 0.004, 0.001, 0.1, 0.003, 0.0005, 0.003
20, 0.1, 0.003, 0.0005, 0.003, 0.003, 0.1, 0.4, 0.33
25, 0.9, 0.63, 0.0005, 0.003, 0.0005, 0.003, 0.1, 0.003
26, 0.08, 0.83, 0.0005, 0.003, 0.1, 0.003, 0.0005, 0.003
39, 0.003, 0.1, 0.4, 0.33, 0.9, 0.63, 0.0005, 0.003
```

(First column is age, the rest are numbers between 0 and 1).

And here is how to use it:

```
data1_df = pd.read_csv("GSE106648_data1.csv")
data2_df = pd.read_csv("GSE106648_data2.csv")

# Split the data
X1, y1 = data1_df.values[:,1:], data1_df.values[:,0]
X2, y2 = data2_df.values[:,1:], data2_df.values[:,0]

X1_train, X1_valid, y1_train, y1_valid = train_test_split(X1, y1, test_size=0.2, shuffle= True)
X2_train, X2_valid, y2_train, y2_valid = train_test_split(X2, y2, test_size=0.2, shuffle= True)
```

How I reshaped it:

```
sample_size = X1_train.shape[0] # number of samples in train set
time_steps  = X1_train.shape[1] # number of features in train set
input_dimension = 1               # each feature is represented by 1 number

# We need to reshape the Test and validation data as well:
X1_train_reshaped = X1_train.reshape(X1_train.shape[0],X1_train.shape[1],1)
X1_valid_reshaped = X1_valid.reshape(X1_valid.shape[0],X1_valid.shape[1],1)
X2_train_reshaped = X2_train.reshape(X2_train.shape[0],X2_train.shape[1],1)
X2_valid_reshaped = X2_valid.reshape(X2_valid.shape[0],X2_valid.shape[1],1)
X1_reshaped = X1.reshape(X1.shape[0],X1.shape[1],1)
X2_reshaped = X2.reshape(X2.shape[0],X2.shape[1],1)
```

And the model:

```
def conv1D_model():
    n_timesteps = X1_train_reshaped.shape[1] 
    n_features  = X1_train_reshaped.shape[2] #1 
    
    model = Sequential(name="model_conv1D")
    model.add(layers.Input(shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))    
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=8, kernel_size=4, activation='LeakyReLU', name="Conv1D_1"))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4, name="MaxPooling1D_1"))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(50, activation='LeakyReLU', name="Dense_1"))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(layers.Dense(n_features, activation='LeakyReLU', name="output"))
    
    optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)

    model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=optimizer,metrics=['mae'])
    return model

my_model = conv1D_model()
history = my_model.fit(X1_train_reshaped,y1_train,batch_size=50,epochs=100,validation_data=(X1_valid_reshaped,y1_valid), shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I guess my question is more like which dimension should correspond to which? What would be batch_size, number of channels and length of signal in my data set.

Comment: There could be several options. It’s impossible to know which is right for your use case unless you provide what you expect the computation (and thus the output thereof) should look like.

Comment: I added my code. Is there at first glance something that isn't right? I'm unsure of the CNN topology.

Comment: The question needs improvements. First, your code uses Keras and not PyTorch right? Please remove the tag `pytorch` and add `keras`. Also, please post a minimal input **as text** (not link) so we can copy and paste it to test your code. Lastly, please describe the issue with your current code that you want us to help solve. E.g., what’s the error you get when you run it?

Comment: Changes were made. In general that the performance is too poor. My advisor said that I might have chosen the wrong encoding.

Answer (score 3):

Few remarks in general, some I'll pose as questions as thinking about them might help you progress as well.

- Why is `X` written in capital letters, while your `y` is denoted small? Is this vector vs matrix?
- Trying to reproduce your code, it would also be great to see which packages (and versions) you are using.

In my case you will be able to reproduce with

```
python == 3.9
keras == 2.11.0
tensorflow == 2.11.0
pandas == 1.5.2
```

- What do your cryptic (at least for me) input features stand for? Which range of value can you expect from them (you answered that one already)?
- What is it your model tries to predict (oh I see the age)? What is the range of values for your expected output value (becomes clearer once we know your target is age)?
- What is the difference between `data1` and `data2`? Is this your train-validation-test split? But then you split it again in the code, and finally only use `X1` for training? Something has to be straightened out here. (I will go ahead and assume that `X1` is train and validate while `X2` is the pure test set - which is arguably good practice).

**Some things on architecture**

A convolutional model is perfect for image data, where you have spatial links between pixel, while at the same time you expect pattern to reemerge along the whole image within a convolutional filter, so you benefit from weight sharing. These characteristics I can not see in your problem.

I would go and try with a fully connected model first.

```
def architecture(num_features):
    # fewer layers will probably also do the trick
    model = Sequential(name="model_Dense")
    model.add(layers.Input(shape=(1, num_features)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_features, activation='LeakyReLU', name="Dense_1"))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(layers.Dense(30, activation='LeakyReLU', name="Dense_2"))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='LeakyReLU', name="Dense_3"))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='LeakyReLU', name="output"))

    optimizer = optimizers.Adam()

    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mae'])
    return model
```

I might be wrong as I do not know your data - 10 minutes later, going down your rabbit whole I realized you are talking of time stamps in your code - I hope your samples have the same reference time stamp at the beginning otherwise we will really have to rethink the whole approach - maybe going in the direction of recurrent neural networks, or you will have to do some proper preprocessing.

Again after realizing that your sample has an input dimension of 10k values. To me everything shouts preprocessing. Can you maybe downsample your feature size? This depends on your sample rate and again the type of data and pattern you are trying to learn from (a plot of a timeseries would have also helped so much while answering your question and understanding your data).

**Some things on reshaping**

If I understood your task correctly, you get an input vector of some fancy (I guess genes? Or something "biology") and then want to predict a single value (the age).

To me the way you load the data is pretty much fine already.

```
# prepare samples and ground truth
X1, y1 = data1_df.values[:, 1:], data1_df.values[:, 0]

num_samples = X1.shape[0]
num_features = X1.shape[1]
X1 = X1.reshape(num_samples, 1, num_features)
```

I do away with the validation splitting by using the `keras` inbuilt validation_split function where you only have to set the percentage of samples that is then used for validation.

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1, validation_split=0.2, epochs=1)
```

For reproducibility it is advised to set a seed.

```
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed(2)
```

**First training run and sanity checking**

Things to check. When increasing your dropout a lot will not decrease your accuracy you probably can do away with quite some input values - meaning decreasing the sample rate.

You have only 67 samples in data1 (everything shouts Augmentation or collect more data), so a batch size larger than that, is meaningless, while a batch size of 67 would mean you only have a single weight update step in a single epoch. Which is great for gradient estimation, but probably not too compute efficient, when your dataset size increases.

I did train this thing because that is the fun part. After 100 epochs I feel like I pretty much converged already - at an error of approx. 7 years - you tell me whether that prediction accuracy is already good enough for what you are trying to achieve.

```
Epoch 98/100
7/7 [==============================] - 2s 278ms/step - loss: 261.2974 - mae: 12.7917 - val_loss: 81.9025 - val_mae: 7.2442
Epoch 99/100
7/7 [==============================] - 2s 277ms/step - loss: 269.4073 - mae: 13.1898 - val_loss: 64.5845 - val_mae: 6.4933
Epoch 100/100
7/7 [==============================] - 2s 276ms/step - loss: 251.1944 - mae: 12.9838 - val_loss: 70.1897 - val_mae: 6.6773
```

An easy next step to decrease your error could be to cast your prediction to an Integer. As your ground truth are all Integers. However that again depends on which prediction resolution (year, month, etc.) you require.

Looks like a fun project. You'll manage

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. Yes X is a matrix, that's why it's in capitals. X1 and X2 are train and test sets. But I'm doing 2 fold cross validation, so in the second split X1 becomes test and X2 train. The features are methylation degrees along different sites in the DNA which can range from 0 to 1.

Comment: I have very few samples and thousands of features. I filtered them using Pearson Correlation coefficient. Initially they were even more.

Comment: With a single hidden layer neural network the MAE value is around 3 so I was looking for ways to improve it. I did hypeparameter tuning and it seems the performance does not depend a lot on the topology. I increased layers, added dropout increased neurons, etc. The best performance for this dataset is around 1.5 with other methods.

Comment: How can I augment my data artificially?

Comment: I have been on christmas holidays and am a little sad to not have been granted the full bounty. This should direct you towards augmentation: https://www.kaggle.com/general/78929

Comment: Hi Mrk I do appreciate the time you took in answering my question. But ultimately it didn't improve the performance. And it seems the link you provided gives worse performance than without data augmentation.

Comment: Are we talking validation performance? Because it is kind of expected that your training performance goes down with augmentation - that's kind of the idea. Also it should not only be about naively making that performance number go up (this is but only one metric) - but who am I to judge.

Comment: Nope, both test and training performance were worse. I also tried SMOTE and this: https://lasse-schmidt90.medium.com/deep-tabular-augmentation-for-regression-tasks-81c1dfdb41d4. The former gave worse test and training performance. The latter gave NaN when computing loss function.